# Putting Ads on HighOnCoding Placements

Tags: google-adsense

I run highoncoding.com and I place adsense ads on the website. i have tons of content on the website but I am not making any progress in making money off the adsense. What advice can u give me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users who click on AdSense ads are generally not technically-savvy.

Find a business model that works for technically-savvy users.

> The simple fact is that web savvy
>   folks are a lot less likely to click
>   ads than those who are less well
>   versed in the online world.

[How Reader Demographics Affect Earnings with Adsense, Chitika, and Other Pay-Per-Click Programs](http://www.writingforyourwealth.com/blogging-for-bucks/how-reader-demographics-affect-earnings-with-adsense-chitika-and-other-pay-per-click-programs/)

Comment: +1 - I have _never_ had any success with Google AdSense on any kind of technical blog or site.

Comment: +1 I have never clicked on an AdSense add on any website.  They just aren't useful.